# convert Map<String,dynamic> data to class data

Tags: flutter, dart

in my application and one of screen i pass class data with `Map<String,dynamic>` to another screen,

```
onTap: (){
  Map<String,dynamic> dataMap = Map<String,dynamic>();
  dataMap['id']=tickets[index].id;
  dataMap['subject']=tickets[index].subject;
  dataMap['createdAt']=tickets[index].createdAt;
  dataMap['ticketNumber']=tickets[index].ticketNumber;

  Navigation.router.navigateTo(context, 'showTicketReplies/$dataMap',transition: TransitionType.fadeIn);
  },
```

in another screen i can get this data with this structure:

```
widget.ticketData = {_InternalLinkedHashMap} size = 1
 0 = {map entry} "id" -> [_GrowableList]
  key = "id"
  value = {_GrowableList} size = 1
   0 = "{
           id: 1, 
           subject: hello world, 
           createdAt: 2019-01-01, 
           ticketNumber: 3381
        }"
```

now i want to make simple variable of class with this data:

```
TicketsTableData get _ticket => TicketsTableData.fromJson(widget.ticketData.values.toList()[0][0]);
```

which that `widget.ticketData.values.toList()[0][0]` value is:

```
{id: 1, subject: hello world, createdAt:2019-01-01, ticketNumber: 3381}
```

but when i try it i get this error:

```
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

## UPDATE

i think i should convert that to `json` before make class data. for example:

```
TicketsTableData get _ticket => TicketsTableData.fromJson(json.encode(widget.ticketData.values.toList()[0][0].toString()));
```

but i get `json` without any quote

Comment: can you post your TicketsTableData JSON here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!!!

```
onTap: (){
  var dataMap ={};
  dataMap["id"]           = tickets[index].id;
  dataMap["subject"]      = tickets[index].subject;
  dataMap["createdAt"]    = tickets[index].createdAt;
  dataMap["ticketNumber"] = tickets[index].ticketNumber;

  Navigation.router.navigateTo(context, 'showTicketReplies/${json.encode(dataMap)}',transition: TransitionType.fadeIn);
},
```